# React + typescript + webpack and ui-router-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, url-routing

I have been following the `ui-router-react` docs (https://ui-router.github.io/react/) I am having a lot of issues with webpack compiling my codebase when importing

```
import {UIRouter, UIView, UISref, UISrefActive, pushStateLocationPlugin} from 'ui-router-react';
```

into app.tsx is when I get these errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/common/common.d.ts:388:31
    TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/common/common.d.ts:388:34
    TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/resolve/resolveContext.d.ts:7:22
    TS7005: Variable 'NATIVE_INJECTOR_TOKEN' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/transition/transitionHook.d.ts:13:37
    TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

ERROR in [at-loader] src/components/loginComponent.tsx:23:33
    TS2314: Generic type 'KeyboardEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [at-loader] src/components/loginComponent.tsx:32:31
    TS2314: Generic type 'KeyboardEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

I thought in my `webpack.config.js` webpack isn't suppose to be looking at `node_modules` but clearly it is.

Here is link to repo under branch reactRouting

https://github.com/JMStudiosJoe/ReactPractice/tree/reactRouting

Comment: There are too many questions here to answer concretely. Consider breaking them down into isolated questions which include the config and breaking component/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like these errors are the result of how the typings for `ui-router-react` were generated.

If you look, say into the `node_modules\ui-router-core\lib\common\common.d.ts` file.\, line `388`, you'll see this

```
export declare type sortfn = (a, b) => number;
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` have no type information assoc. w/ them. If you manually edit this line so that it instead looks like

```
export declare type sortfn = (a: any, b: any) => number;
```

the first two compile errors will be gone. And if go to each file/line in the error list you provided and do the same, you project will compile.

Now, it's, of course a temporary measure, and the real types should be something other than `any`. This (i.e., the typings) should be fixed by the authors of the package. However, editing the type definition files in this manner will unblock you for now.

Comment: Yes I noticed that but anytime I run npm install will need to change those files again so not a great workaround but your right it is one.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue but I was looking in the webpack config when the solutions were in the tsconfig file. You can set the option of `"noImplicitAny": false`  to get rid of the any errors

> into app.tsx is when I get these errors: ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/common/common.d.ts:388:31 TS7006: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/common/common.d.ts:388:34 TS7006: Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/resolve/resolveContext.d.ts:7:22 TS7005: Variable 'NATIVE_INJECTOR_TOKEN' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/ui-router-core/lib/transition/transitionHook.d.ts:13:37 TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

To get rid of the other errors took manipulating my types of React function parameters

```
usernameValidator = (event: React.KeyboardEvent => {
```

changed to

```
usernameValidator = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
```

fixed the last 2 issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not set `"noImplicitAny"` to `true` because it is very useful, in your own codebase, to ensure you are fully taking advantage of one of the power of Typescript (type checking).

Your issue here is that your typescript transpiler is processing your node_modules libraries. And you don't really want that because you trust your third party libraries.

The easiest way to stop that is to simply add an `exclude` field in your `tsconfig.json` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

If your `tsconfig.json` is at the root folder, and same for your node_modules folder, you can add that:

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

And...that's it!